# How to put random speed on the position of the y-axis only?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Sorry, I'm a beginner in Unity but I want to move a gameobject on the Y-axis only and have it move with random speed so that sometimes it moves fast and sometimes slower.

this is my code. (it jitters because i figured out my mistake is I put the random speed on the update but I don't know how to fix it)

```
public class RandomUpDown : MonoBehaviour
{
     [SerializeField] float minSpeed = 1f;

     [SerializeField] float maxSpeed = 2f;
     
     [SerializeField] float height = 4f;

     Vector3 pos;

     private void Start()
     {
         pos = transform.position;
     }

     void Update()
     {
        float randomSpeed = Random.Range(minSpeed, maxSpeed);
        float newY = Mathf.Sin(Time.time * randomSpeed) * height + pos.y;  
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, newY, transform.position.z);
     } 
}
```

Comment: well when and how often and how fast do you want to change the random speed?

Comment: Maybe around every 2 seconds? Should I do a coroutine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it really depends on what you want, but you can do this with a coroutine and a loop.

for example:

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(myRandLoop)
}

public IEnumerator myRandLoop()
{
    while(true)
    {
        float randomSpeed = Random.Range(minSpeed, maxSpeed);
        float newY = Mathf.Sin(Time.time * randomSpeed) * height + pos.y;  
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, newY, transform.position.z);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delayAmount)
    }
}
```

Comment: You could directly make `private IEnumerator Start() { while(true){...} }` btw ;)

Comment: I used a coroutine and randomized the height instead. Thank you for the tip!